# Amazon S3 permission denied error for Lambda function for PutObjectTagging adding tags post-upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Trying to have tags automatically added to objects post-upload following this guide
https://heywoodonline.com/posts/Automatically%20Tagging%20Uploads%20to%20S3.html
But when the function runs I'm getting the following error

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObjectTagging operation: Access Denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 37, in lambda_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 22, in lambda_handler
    response = s3.put_object_tagging(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

I've checked the Role that's created found in the Configuration menu
[config menu Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWWs2.png)

Editing that brings me to this policy, which I've added a bunch of Actions to.

[image: Policy]

Anything I add to the policy seems to be ignored as I continue to get the same Access Denied error.

Other similar posts to stackOverflow do not mention what policy needs to be edited but when I search the roles there is only one with the title I gave it. It's got to be the one.

What am I missing?

**EDIT: FIXED!**
I added a new resource to the above policy and it worked as needed.

```
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:367384020442:log-group:/aws/lambda/addTagPostUpload:*",
"arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
]
```

Comment: It looks like you started with an IAM Policy to grant access to CloudWatch Logs, and then tried editing it to include S3 permissions. You shouldn't mix the two of them in the same statement, since the target resources are different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your policy as text as opposed to an image which cannot be indexed etc.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried to find how to add another policy but could not locate it. I'll check again but for now the above change worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You policy only mentioned 'logs' resources and not s3 resources. Unless you specify what s3 resources your s3 actions have permissions  on, it does not matter what you put in actions. Right now the policy says you have s3 and logs action permissions on the specified cloudwatch log group and nothing else

Comment: Yes! That was it exactly. I added a new resource to the above policy and it worked as needed. This formatting in the comments sucks! I'll add it to my original post.

"Resource": [
"arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:367384020442:log-group:/aws/lambda/addTagPostUpload:*",
"arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
]